# Device Protection locked me out

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-account, locked-out, htc-one

I just ordered a new **HTC One M9**, which arrived today. The ones I previously ordered came preinstalled with Android 5.0, so I just created a new Google Account (`tmp<random_number_of_random_numbers>@gmail.com`) for upgrading the system to the current 6.0 version. I did not know about the [Device Protection Feature](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/03/12/guide-what-is-android-5-1s-antitheft-device-protection-feature-and-how-do-i-use-it/), so I did not provide any additional information like a phone number or so. I just checked the system's software version and found it to already be 6.0, so I rebooted and hard resetted the phone via boot loader to have a fresh install of the current version.

Now I wanted to sign in with my real account and got stopped by the following message:

> This device was reset. To continue, sign in with a Google Account that was previously synced on this device.

The problem is: I don't remember the mail address I used. I still know the password, but that alone is of no worth, as you might imagine.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Have you checked with our [google-account tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-account/info) already and followed the link to the relevant post? ;)

Comment: No answers working for me. I even called Google support and they told me to send the device back and ask for a new one...